# Dependency injection by the condition in the runtime

Tags: java, spring, dependency-injection, autowired, lombok

Suppose, there is the following code:

```
@RestController
@RequiredArgsConstructor(onConstructor = @__(@Autowired))
class Controller {

    /* inject here */
    public @NonNull GenericService service;

    public void doo(List<GenericDTO> list, String type) {
        service.doo(list);
    }

}

class GenericDTO { ... }
class GenericService { ... }

class OfferService extends GenericService { ... }
class OtherService extends GenericService { ... }
```

If `type` from `doo` method is equal to `"offer"`, I want to inject an  `OfferService` instance to `service`. If I receive `"other"`, I have to use `OtherService`, and so on. Is that possible?

Comment: Well, no. This is a single field. It will be injected once (if it's a singleton bean). The injection logic will not have access to a value present within a method invocation. Just inject both services and use an `if` to decide. Alternatively, create a `Map` to pick the appropriate service based on the key type.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume all your beans are singletons.

Singleton beans are all initialized and injected during context initialization which happens at application startup, ie. your `doo` method (which I assume is meant to be a handler method) has yet to be invoked. There's no way for Spring to guess/know what are possible values for invoking some method or how those values should in any way influence a target injection point.

Maybe a proxy could help and determine during invocation of `doo` what real bean to get. This is difficult because you have to somehow expose the value of `type` to whatever component does the resolution. Spring can't do this out of the box. You'll have to write your own piece to do this, probably with the help of your own `Scope` implementation. (This is not trivial.)

The simplest solution is to inject both services and just `if-else`/`switch` on `type` and pick one accordingly. Or put both services in a `Map` with the `type` being the key.

Answer (score 0):

I accomplish this with one of the 2 patterns below whenever I need to pick an implementation at runtime. It is strictly not what you are asking for - bean is not injected conditionally, but is invoked conditionally.

Also this will be elegant if you have a small set of GenericService implementations. If it is a larger set or if the class heirarchy is deeper, then this might be not-so-elegant solution.

However, this accomplishes the goal of not having to change the invoking code when a new GenericService implementation is added as also gives you the capability to inject different subset of service implementations into different Controllers.

```
Class MyController {

    Map<String, GenericService> servicesMap = new HashMap<String, GenericService>(); 

    @Autowired
    public setServices(List<GenericService> serviceList) {
        for (GenericService service : serviceList) {
             if (service instanceof OfferService) {
                serviceMap.put("offer", service);
             }
             if (service instanceof OtherService) {
                serviceMap.put("other", service);
             }
    }

    public void doo(List<GenericDTO> list, String type) {
        GenericService service = serviceMap.get(type);
        if (null != service) {
             service.doo(list);
        }
    }
}
```

Another possible and probably more elegant solution could be to have the implementation class indicate what type it actually supports.

```
Class GenericService {

     // This method could very well be an abstract method or a simple
     // getter for a property set through ctor

     public String getType() {
          return "unknown"; // or "generic" if you please
     }

}

Class OfferClass extends GenericService {
     @Override
     public String getType() {
          return "offer";
     }
}

Class OtherClass extends GenericService {
     @Override
     public String getType() {
          return "other";
     }
}

Class MyController {

    Map<String, GenericService> servicesMap = new HashMap<String, GenericService>(); 
    // This is just there so that we do not have to process the 
    // list everytime we need to invoke the service

    @Autowired
    public setServices(List<GenericService> serviceList) {
        for (GenericService service : serviceList) {
            serviceMap.put(service.getType(), service)
        }
    }

    public void doo(List<GenericDTO> list, String type) {
        GenericService service = serviceMap.get(type);
        if (null != service) {
             service.doo(list);
        }
    }
}
```